# how to start wget in cmd with start command and show only progress bar?

Tags: windows, cmd, wget

I want to download a file with [wget portable](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/) using start command in cmd, with a batch file, but the window looks bad:

```
@echo off
start /w wget.exe -q -c --show-progress https://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-workbench-community-8.0.23-winx64.msi
```

[image]

What should I add to my command, to reduce the window to the size of the progress bar? (and if possible change the black background color and the color of the letters)

Comment: Does removing the `start /w` improve the situation?

Comment: There is no difference, but I need to run it with start / w for special requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download progress window could be opened with the wanted properties with following command line:

```
start "Download Progress" /wait %ComSpec% /D /T:fg /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\mode.com CON COLS=80 LINES=1 & wget.exe -q -c --show-progress https://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-workbench-community-8.0.23-winx64.msi"
```

The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` processing the batch file starts with command `start` one more command processor referenced with predefined environment variable `ComSpec` with the options:

- `/D` to disable execution of `AutoRun` commands from registry,
- `/T:fg` to define the **f**oreground and **b**ackground color (both 0-9A-F) of the console window,
- `/C` to execute the command line specified next and then close itself.

The options are explained by the usage help output on running `cmd /?` in an opened [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window.

The title for the console window is `Download Progress` as defined already by `start` which waits for self-termination of started `cmd.exe` instance. Run `start /?` in command prompt window for help on this command.

The command line executed by the started command process first runs command **MODE** to change the number of columns to 80 and the number of lines to 1, i.e. the additional console window becomes very small. Run `mode /?` in command prompt window for help on this command.

The small additional console window displays only the progress information of `wget.exe` which is executed next by the second command processor instance.

See also [single line with multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of the operator `&`.